# Cannot use Disc Defragger

Tags: windows

I'm not sure which part of stackexchange to put this in.

I have been trying to defrag my hard drive due to slower than usuall run speeds.

Everytime I have been trying to use the disk defragger, it won't open.  Sometimes I get no errors, just nothing happens.  Sometimes, I get the error "disk in use".  I read on another forum that for "disk in use", you need to enable the DCom Launch Process, but I've already done that.

I don't know what to do.  Some other sites say that the defragger wont work because other defragger's are installed, but i dont have any defraggers, and the only "cpu" related software my computer has is CPU-Z.

If this is the wrong site, could someone help move it? I'm not really good with tech and I have no clue which site to post this in.

Comment: I think you want our sister site, [Super User](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: The question as it stands would be a poor fit even on Super User. You have confused a number of things and it's far from clear that you even know what to ask. See if you can get someone to help you with the wording.

Comment: See if you can get someone to help you with your manners. At least Michael tried to help

Comment: Believe it or not, I was also helping. Too bad you didn't recognise it for what it was and instead got your nose out of joint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To help you with your issue, you could give us some information like "What operating system are you running", and "do you have any error events logged in the event viewer at the time you start Disc Defragmenter".

The best I can suggest without better info would be to install [Defraggler](http://www.piriform.com/defraggler) as it supports Windows XP through Windows Server 2008. I use it myself, and it's absolutely free.